# WindowStateChanged not being fired in Internet Explorer BHO

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, bho

NavigateComplete, DocumentComplete, etc work just fine but for some reason WindowStateChanged doesn't. I am testing with IE9. Has this event been deperecated?

```
public class BHO : IObjectWithSite, IOleCommandTarget
{

    IWebBrowser2 browser = null;
    int version = 9;

    void OnNavigateComplete2(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(pDisp, browser))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            var document = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
            var window = document.parentWindow;
            Debug.WriteLine(version + "MainURL: " + URL.ToString());
        }
    }

    void OnWindowStateChanged(uint dwWindowStateFlags, uint dwValidFlagsMask)
    {
        version = version * 2;   //never hit
        Debug.WriteLine(version);
    }

    #region Implementation of IObjectWithSite
    int IObjectWithSite.SetSite(object site)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SetSite!");
        if (site != null)
        {
            browser = (IWebBrowser2)site;
            ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)browser).NavigateComplete2 +=
       new WebBrowserEvents2_NavigateComplete2EventHandler
              (this.OnNavigateComplete2);
             ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)browser).WindowStateChanged +=
       new WebBrowserEvents2_WindowStateChangedEventHandler
              (this.OnWindowStateChanged);

        }

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me half a day but I got it.

By default VS embeds SHDocVw into your BHO, and even though it works, some of the handlers don't fire. I guess IE ends up using a different SHDocVw?

Anyway. by setting embed interop to 'false' and registering it with GAC, the events start firing again. All of them.